# Index scan on SQL update statement

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, indexing

I have the following SQL statement, which I would like to make more efficient.  Looking through the execution plan I can see that there is a Clustered Index Scan on @newWebcastEvents. Is there a way I can make this into a seek?  Or are there any other ways I can make the below more efficient?

```
declare @newWebcastEvents table (
    webcastEventId int not null primary key clustered (webcastEventId) with (ignore_dup_key=off)
)

insert into @newWebcastEvents
select wel.WebcastEventId
from WebcastChannelWebcastEventLink wel with (nolock)
where wel.WebcastChannelId = 1178

Update WebcastEvent
set WebcastEventTitle = LEFT(WebcastEventTitle, CHARINDEX('(CLONE)',WebcastEventTitle,0) - 2)
where
WebcastEvent.WebcastEventId in (select webcastEventId from @newWebcastEvents)
```

Comment: Its just a temp table and no just the primary key.  The table is small, only up to a maximum of 15 rows. the table that I am updating could has thousands of rows though.

Comment: There are about 5000 rows in WebcastChannelWebcastEventLink,  there are about 15 rows of this table being selected into @newWebcastEvents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@newWebcastEvents` table variable only contains the only single column, and you're asking for **all rows** of that table variable in this where clause:

```
where
   WebcastEvent.WebcastEventId in (select webcastEventId from @newWebcastEvents)
```

So doing a **seek** on this clustered index is usually rather pointless - SQL Server query optimizer will need **all columns, all rows** of that table variable anyway..... so it chooses an index scan.

I don't think this is a performance issue, anyway.

An index seek is useful if you need to pick a very small number of rows (<= 1-2% of the original number of rows) from a large table. Then, going through the clustered index navigation tree and finding those few rows involved makes a lot more sense than scanning the whole table. But here, with a single `int` column and 15 rows --> it's absolutely pointless to seek, it will be **much faster** to just read those 15 `int` values in a single scan and be done with it...

**Update:** no sure if it makes any difference in terms of performance, but I personally typically prefer to use **joins** rather than subselects for "connecting" two tables:

```
UPDATE we
SET we.WebcastEventTitle = LEFT(we.WebcastEventTitle, CHARINDEX('(CLONE)', we.WebcastEventTitle, 0) - 2)
FROM dbo.WebcastEvent we
INNER JOIN @newWebcastEvents nwe ON we.WebcastEventId = nwe.webcastEventId
```

Comment: Oh right Ok cheers.  This query isn't taking long to run, I am just trying to improve my knowledge.  I have been told to try and avoid index scans in my queries so was just trying to rectify this, but the above makes sense.  Would you say this is the most efficient way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: @user3284707: yes, I would also recommend trying to avoid index scans - on really **large tables**, e.g. 100'000 rows or more - if you need to extract only a handful of rows (1-2% of the total) from those tables. But 15 `int` values - that's **60 bytes** which is a lot less than the 8K that a single page is - and SQL Server always loads based on pages......

Comment: Great thanks for that, I will look at changing my update to this if this is considered best practice.  Thanks for your help.